# HTML Bootstrap 3 + Table grid Появляется неизвестный артефакт

Tags: html, css

Я создал с помощью Bootstrap сетку, добавил туда padding-bottom и создал квадраты.
В квадраты я запихнул контейнер .inner-container и в него запихнул таблицу.
Добавил css стили,  видно что у таблиц есть отступы. Рядом с красным и зелеными, между ними какой отступ

Видно только на больших экранов, отступ между таблицами, но я их убрать не могу...

В контейнере .small-block-content тоже самое происходит.

Вот [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/solunski/0Lb3u83z/5/)

```
    <div class="container-fluid content">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- MAIN -->
        <main class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 large-block-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 large-block">
                            <div class="inner-container">
                                <div class="table">
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 large-block">
                            <div class="inner-container">
                                <div class="table">
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 middle-block-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 middle-block">
                            <div class="inner-container">
                                <div class="table">
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 middle-block">
                            <div class="inner-container">
                                <div class="table">
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 small-block-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 small-block">
                            <div class="inner-container">
                                <div class="table">
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 small-block">
                            <div class="inner-container">
                                <div class="table">
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 small-block">
                            <div class="inner-container">
                                <div class="table">
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                        <div class="table-cell"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <!-- /.MAIN -->

        <!-- ASIDE -->
        <aside class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 aside">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 small-block"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 small-block"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 small-block"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 small-block empty"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 small-block empty"></div>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <!-- /.ASIDE -->
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Вот ссылка на изображении проблемы, смотрю со своего монитора http://s020.radikal.ru/i715/1601/93/876215423445.jpg Там где красный блок,рамка не до конца и где голубые блоки имеется отступ между ними

Comment: вообще на flex-box или же на обычном css в несколько строк это реализуется , а bootstrap ни когда не уважал , надо сначала их вёрстку изучить , а потом применять , потому и не применяю этот фрамворк

Comment: Вы уверенны что дело в Bootstrap ибо элемент .table с указанным стилем width: 100%; все равно не дотягивается...

Comment: @Solunski.D, а зачем вы использовали свой класс с `position:abcolute`? даже нет. почему вы вообще везде бутстраповскую сетку не использовали?

Comment: Чтобы все блоки были ровными. http://s019.radikal.ru/i628/1601/6b/37c8354dd392.jpg Мне нужно чтобы каждый блок был бы квадратом.

Comment: кроме того на jsfiddle вы используете обычный css, которые не понимает правила _.small-block-content {
  .small-block {_

Comment: Да, забыл что less не поддерживает ;)

Comment: @Solunski.D, там можно поставить поддержку scss в настройках

Comment: вот ссылка https://jsfiddle.net/solunski/0Lb3u83z/6/ поменял на scss

Comment: ну и еще могу сказать, что проблема в округлениях, если посмотрите, для `inner-container` ширина рассчиталась - `296.938` а для вложенного `table` = `296`

Comment: @Grundy я вот это не могу понять почему???

Comment: очевидно по тому, что по разному рассчитываются :)

Comment: @Grundy и как быть теперь? Либо переделывать, либо js

Comment: мне кажется проще переделать, честно говоря таки не понял зачем вам этот блок inner-container

Comment: @Grundy сетку поставить. http://f-picture.net/lfp/s019.radikal.ru/i628/1601/6b/37c8354dd392.jpg/htm С помощью ее я делаю все блоки ровными

Comment: Это не просто так, все блоки ровные в зависимости от экрана

Comment: а откуда такие числа вообще взялись? _50.33333333%_,  _100.66666667%_

Comment: Нуу тут я не много потупил, числа от ширины блоков. Нужен был квадрат.

Comment: Mozzila все верно высчитывает...